# Hacer res.send() a una información obtenida en un find que se encuentra dentro de un map

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

Mi pregunta viene a raíz de que necesitaba hacer un find y luego con los resultados de este hacer otro, por lo que decidí usar el método map, esto funciono perfectamente y el resultado del find dentro del map es el que deseaba, el problema viene cuando intento hacer res.send() a esos valores, para que se entienda mejor lo explico con el código:

```
TG.find({_teacher:req.user.sub}).then((teachers)=>{

    if(!teachers.length) {
        res.status(404).send({message:'No tienes grupos'});
    }else{
       // aquí hice el map
        teachers.map((teacher)=>{
            Groups.find({_id:teacher._group}).then((groups)=>{
                console.log(groups);
            });
        });
    }

}).catch((err)=>{
    res.status(500).send({message:'error'})
});
```

En el anterior código se puede ver que hice un map y dentro de este hice un find ,el cual mostré en consola, esto es lo que me devuelve:

```
[ { _id: 5aa06e56f205d22808a87d0f,
    image: 'aoidmoadmosa.jpg',
    school: 'example',
    name: 'grupo1',
    __v: 0 } ]
[ { _id: 5aa0801c0cbbf023a0d4eae0,
    image: '7MdRCNxrGV34xsSah1eUe8-l.jpeg',
    school: 'example',
    name: 'grupo2',
    __v: 0 } ]
[ { _id: 5aa070c616d8b941cce2a4f6,
    image: 'RwnQFELG4Kr_18lz7ehB6APh.jpeg',
    school: 'example',
    name: 'grupo3',
    __v: 0 } ]
[ { _id: 5aa09e4254fbe11514a02ed1,
    image: '7-DwBHQqJqRcBGxRVD_zdtMx.jpeg',
    school: 'example',
    name: 'grupo4',
    __v: 0 } ]
```

Lo que quiero conseguir es hacer una respuesta de estos objetos, pero al intentar en lugar de hacer un console.log() hacer res.send() me aparece un unico objeto, esto es claramente porque el send interrumpe el map en el 'primer ciclo', por lo que necesito saber como una vez se complete el map, extraer el contenido del find y asi poder mostrar todos los objetos.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente lo conseguí de esta forma:

```
TG.find({_teacher:req.user.sub}).then((teachers)=>{
        if(!teachers.length){
            res.status(404).send({message:'No tienes grupos'});
        }else{
            var group_array = [];
            groups_promise = teachers.map((teacher)=>{
                return Groups.find({_id:teacher._group}).then((groups)=>{
                    group_array = group_array + groups;
                });


            });
            //esto es lo primero que se lee, y lo que hace es ejecuar la 
            promesa, para luego responder con otra, usando el then para que 
            cuando la anterior promesa se termine de ejecutar esta se 
            ejecute haciendo el res.send() 
            return Promise.all(groups_promise).then(()=>{
                res.status(200).send({groups:group_array});
            });
        }

    }).catch(()=>{
        res.status(500).send({message:"Error al buscar tus grupos"});
    });
```